# User login on Flask?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I've been working through chapters 3 and 4 of the Flask mega-tutorial (https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database). I'm trying to set up user logins on my flask webpage that I have hosted at pythonanywhere. I'm able to register an account successfully (I can see the record added to my database), however, when I try to login, Flask is unable to find the record when searching for the username and it returns None. I'm not sure why this is happening. Complicating things a bit is that I'm using a MySQL database rather than a SQLLite database that the tutorial uses.

config.py:

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

class Config(object):
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or 'something'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://username:password@jplank.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com/jplank$default'
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

flask_app.py:

```
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.urls import url_parse
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, request
from pandas import DateOffset, DataFrame, date_range, to_datetime
from flask_login import current_user, login_user, logout_user, login_required, LoginManager
import MySQLdb
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from numpy import nan
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import datetime
import math
from yearfrac import CalcYearFrac
import decimal
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
login = LoginManager(app)
login.login_view = 'login'
Bootstrap(app)

from forms import NameForm, LoginForm, RegistrationForm
import routes, models

@app.route('/table', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required
def calculatetable():
[...]
```

models.py:

```
from flask_app import db, login
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_login import UserMixin

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.username)

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)

@login.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))
```

routes.py:

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, request
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, current_user
from werkzeug.urls import url_parse
from flask_app import app, db
from forms import LoginForm, RegistrationForm
from models import User
from config import Config

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = 
User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user is None:
            flash('user is none')
            flash(form.username.data)
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        elif not user.check_password(form.password.data):
            flash('not hash match')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        login_user(user, remember=form.remember_me.data)
        next_page = request.args.get('next')
        if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).netloc != '':
            next_page = url_for('calculatetable')
        return redirect(next_page)
    return render_template('login.html', title='Sign In', form=form)

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data)
        user.set_password(form.password.data)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Congratulations, you are now a registered user!')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)
```

Comment: Try changing the table name to, say, "usr" instead: `__tablename__ = "usr"`

Comment: Thanks. I just tried renaming the table to usr and updating the __tablename__ = "usr", but still getting the same problem.

Comment: My apologies, I thought sure that was the problem. It turns out "user" is just a keyword in MySQL, and not a reserved word.

Comment: All the same, I think it's probably best to avoid confusing the SQL parser to be safe.

Comment: I'll look more at your code to see if I can spot an issue.

Comment: In your posted code you have `user = ` then the code continues on the next line... that's not like that in your actual code is it?

Comment: No, it's on the same line in my actual code. I think the formatting just got messed up a bit when I posted here.

Comment: Are you able to query the database independently of your Flask application, and see that the query works?

Comment: I might be able to but I'm not entirely sure how to do it. I'm a bit new to using SQLAlchemy. I can run Python from the command line, but not sure what I need to enter in order to run the query. (Sorry, I'm new to this).

Comment: That's alright. I think it's more than a few comments worth of words and statements to run that query in stand-alone SQLAlchemy fashion. And I think that's a good next step to debugging this.

Comment: I have to call it a night, but I'll check back in tomorrow. Best wishes with the debugging effort.

Comment: Maybe have a look at: https://leportella.com/english/2019/01/10/sqlalchemy-basics-tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks - I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this. There was a problem with the way I'd set up my MySQL table and I didn't have certain columns identified as index. Recreating the table solved the issue.